# creating video from sequence of images javacv

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

For creating video from sequence of images in android I used javacv 0.6 library, but I meet problem:
It normally works on htc Sensation(Android 4.0.1, Processor type armv7) and htc Desire(Android 2.3.3, Processor type arm7) phones, but it doesn't work on htc Wildfire
(Android 2.3.5,Processor type armv6) phone particularly it fails in this part of code

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(videoFilePath,       
TalkingPhotoConstants.VIDEO_FRAME_WIDTH,TalkingPhotoConstants.VIDEO_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

in the attached code.

```
public class MovieCreator extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private opencv_core.IplImage[] iplimage;
private String audioFilePath;


private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Context context;
private List<TalkFrame> frames;

public MovieCreator(Context context, opencv_core.IplImage[] images, String audioFilePath,           
List<TalkFrame> frames) {
    this.context = context;
    this.iplimage = images;
    this.audioFilePath = audioFilePath;
    this.frames = frames;

}

private String createMovie() {

    String videoName = TalkingPhotoConstants.TMP_VIDEO_NAME;
    String path = TalkingPhotoConstants.RESOURCES_TMP_FOLDER;
    String videoFilePath = path + videoName;
    String finalVideoName = TalkingPhotoConstants.FINAL_VIDEO_NAME + 
    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
    String finalVideoPath = TalkingPhotoConstants.RESOURCES_FOLDER + finalVideoName;

    try {

        FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(videoFilePath, 
        TalkingPhotoConstants.VIDEO_FRAME_WIDTH,TalkingPhotoConstants.VIDEO_FRAME_HEIGHT);


        //int frameCount = iplimage.length;
        int frameCount = frames.size();
        recorder.setAudioCodec(AV_CODEC_ID_AMR_NB);
        recorder.setVideoCodec(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);

        recorder.setVideoBitrate(120000);
        recorder.setFrameRate(TalkingPhotoConstants.VIDEO_FRAME_RATE);

        recorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
        recorder.setFormat("mp4");

        recorder.start();


        for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            TalkFrame currentFrame = frames.get(i);
            long duration = currentFrame.getDuration();
            opencv_core.IplImage iplImage = cvLoadImage(currentFrame.getImageName());

            for (int j = 0; j < TalkingPhotoConstants.VIDEO_FRAME_RATE * duration; j++) {
                recorder.record(iplImage);

            }

        }

        recorder.stop();

        mergeAudioAndVideo(videoFilePath, audioFilePath, finalVideoPath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("problem", "problem", e);
        finalVideoName = "";
    }
    return finalVideoName;
}

private boolean mergeAudioAndVideo(String videoPath, String audioPath, String outPut)  
throws Exception {
    boolean isCreated = true;
    File file = new File(videoPath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return false;
    }


    FrameGrabber videoGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
    FrameGrabber audioGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(audioPath);

    videoGrabber.start();
    audioGrabber.start();
    FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(outPut,
            videoGrabber.getImageWidth(), videoGrabber.getImageHeight(),
            audioGrabber.getAudioChannels());


    recorder.setFrameRate(videoGrabber.getFrameRate());
    recorder.start();
    Frame videoFrame = null, audioFrame = null;
    while ((audioFrame = audioGrabber.grabFrame()) != null) {
        videoFrame = videoGrabber.grabFrame();
        if (videoFrame != null) {
            recorder.record(videoFrame);
        }
        recorder.record(audioFrame);

    }
    recorder.stop();
    videoGrabber.stop();
    audioGrabber.stop();
    return isCreated;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    String fileName = createMovie();
    boolean result = fileName.isEmpty();
    if (!result) {
        VideoDAO videoDAO = new VideoDAO(context);
        videoDAO.open();
        videoDAO.createVideo(fileName);
        videoDAO.close();
    }
    //Utils.cleanTmpDir();
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

}

There is no exception.

1.how can i fix it?

2.I have a version that problem is connected with device's processor type.

If I'm right how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaCV contains some native C code that gets invoked by the Java. It looks as though you've got a version that's been compiled for ARMv7 but not for ARMv6.

In order to get it to work, you'll need to recompile the JavaCV native bits, for the processor you're wanting to target (ARMv6 in this case). Once you've done this, you should find it works OK.

Native code is a pain, but it is important for applications like this where it's doing some very CPU-intensive stuff.